# Is there a different voice actress singing the same ending for each arc?

Tags: theme-song, rascal-does-not-dream-of-bunny-girl

I'm pretty sure (but also not certain) that the first episodes about Sakurajima Mai had the same voice actress singing the ending, but then on Episode 4 I noticed that the person singing the ending for that episode sounded like the voice actress for Tomoe Koga.

Does *Rascal Does Not Dream of Bunny Girl Senpai* have a different VA singing the ending for each arc?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rascal_Does_Not_Dream_of_Bunny_Girl_Senpai#Anime),

> The ending theme is "Fukashigi no Karte" (不可思議のカルテ), with each arc using versions by Asami Seto (Mai Sakurajima), Yurika Kubo (Kaede Azusagawa), Nao Tōyama (Tomoe Koga), Atsumi Tanezaki (Rio Futaba), Maaya Uchida (Nodoka Toyohama), and Inori Minase (Shoko Makinohara) under their character names.